# NULL при вызове метода

Tags: php

При вызове метода Registr вылезает null, никак не пойму где накосячил

```
namespace Model\Registration;

require_once 'Db.php';
use Model\Database\Db;

class Registration {

    public $connection;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->connection = Db::Connect();
    }

    public function Registr() {
        if(isset($_POST['btn'])) {
            if(isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['login'] && $_POST['password'] !== "") {
                $dbh = $this->connection;
                $sql = 'INSERT INTO users(email, login, password) VALUES (:email, :login, :password)';
                $sqlParams = [':email' => $_POST['email'], ':login' => $_POST['login'], ':password' => $_POST['password']];
                $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
                $result = $sth->execute($sqlParams);
                header('Location: /');
            } else {
                echo 'Заполните все поля <a href="../View/registration.php"><b>Registration</b></a>';
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: В какой строке ошибка возникает?

Comment: вероятнее всего пост запрос пустой. + к тому  null выводит потому что вы просто вызываете функцию в которой ничего не возвращаете и php пытается вывести return этой функции. поставьте первому if блок else и обработайте ошибку...

Comment: Это код простой регистрации, когда я создаю объект и вызываю метод Registr внутри файла, где этот класс написан, всё работает. Но когда пытаюсь вызвать его через контроллер NULL, изначально были ошибки в обработке данных POST, написал isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['login'] && $_POST['password'] !== "" в итоге вместо ошибок, появился просто null